# useFirestoreConnect with populates - usage/implementation

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

DB Setup:

```
- users
  - A: { // private user info }
- usersPublic
  - A: { // public user info }
- rooms
  - 1: { readAccess: ['A'] }
```

I have a component that displays all `rooms` and am fetching that in the following way:

```
useFirestoreConnect(() => [{collection: 'rooms'}] )
```

This is working fine, but I now want to also load in the info from `usersPublic` for each user in the rooms `readAccess` array.

I'm attempting to use `populates` in the following way:

```
useFirestoreConnect(() => [{
  collection: 'rooms',
  populates: [{
    root: 'usersPublic',
    child: 'A'
  }]
}])
```

I'm pretty sure my implementation of `populates` is wrong and I'm failing to understand exactly how to make this work.

I could return a bunch of other query configs for all users with read access once I have the room object but that seems inefficient and it seems that `populates` is meant to solve exactly this problem.

I'm also open to suggestions on modeling the DB structure - the above made sense to me and offers a nice separation between private/public user info but there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is:

`populates: [{ root: usersPublic, child: 'read_access  ' }]`

This results in a redux state that looks like:

```
...etc
data: {
  rooms: { ... rooms ... }
  usersPublic: { A: { ... usersPublic[A] ... }, etc }
}
```

Comment: Hi i am also facing the same problem can you provide the whole example